# How to read only text without strikethrough in an excel cell through Python?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, strikethrough

I have an excel sheet as shown in the image below which has some cells that contain some text with a strikethrough and some without. Is there a way I can read only the text which does not have a strikethrough? I was able to check for strikethrough formatting using the code below but it only works at cell level. Looking for a solution in python but any other suggestions are welcome
Thanks

[excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icrzG.png)

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(bookName, formatting_info=True)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheetName)
    rows, cols = sheet.nrows, sheet.ncols
    for col in range(cols):
        for row in range(1, rows):
            xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
            xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
            bgx = xf.background.pattern_colour_index
            font = book.font_list[xf.font_index]
            if font.struck_out:
```

Comment: All formatting is always at the cell level.

Answer (score 0):

use can get it by sheet.cell.value() method. you will the value of cell without the formatting

```
sheet.cell.value()
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.